# Find fit function

Tags: fitting, data

I want to find a fit function for the following data. Can someone suggest the best-fit function for the following data? The upper part of the data set is difficult.

```
data = {{0.0270538, 0.92}, {0.0854374, 0.93}, {0.124226, 0.94}, {0.14931, 
  0.95}, {0.16527, 0.96}, {0.175575, 0.97}, {0.182765, 
  0.98}, {0.188613, 0.99}, {0.194274, 1.}, {0.200419, 
  1.01}, {0.207346, 1.02}, {0.215083, 1.03}, {0.223469, 
  1.04}, {0.232232, 1.05}, {0.241039, 1.06}, {0.249549, 
  1.07}, {0.257445, 1.08}, {0.264458, 1.09}, {0.270386, 
  1.1}, {0.275104, 1.11}, {0.278564, 1.12}, {0.280794, 
  1.13}, {0.281891, 1.14}, {0.282012, 1.15}, {0.281358, 
  1.16}, {0.280166, 1.17}, {0.27869, 1.18}, {0.27719, 
  1.19}, {0.275915, 1.2}, {0.275095, 1.21}, {0.274926, 
  1.22}, {0.275567, 1.23}, {0.277128, 1.24}, {0.279669, 
  1.25}, {0.283197, 1.26}, {0.287672, 1.27}, {0.293, 1.28}, {0.299049,
   1.29}, {0.305648, 1.3}, {0.3126, 1.31}, {0.319689, 
  1.32}, {0.326692, 1.33}, {0.333388, 1.34}, {0.339569, 
  1.35}, {0.345052, 1.36}, {0.349685, 1.37}, {0.353355, 
  1.38}, {0.355998, 1.39}, {0.357599, 1.4}, {0.358195, 
  1.41}, {0.357876, 1.42}, {0.356783, 1.43}, {0.3551, 
  1.44}, {0.353051, 1.45}, {0.350887, 1.46}, {0.348878, 
  1.47}, {0.347298, 1.48}, {0.346412, 1.49}, {0.346466, 
  1.5}, {0.347666, 1.51}, {0.350175, 1.52}, {0.35409, 
  1.53}, {0.359445, 1.54}, {0.366196, 1.55}, {0.374222, 
  1.56}, {0.383326, 1.57}, {0.39324, 1.58}, {0.403638, 
  1.59}, {0.414145, 1.6}, {0.424364, 1.61}, {0.43389, 
  1.62}, {0.442339, 1.63}, {0.449372, 1.64}, {0.454715, 
  1.65}, {0.458178, 1.66}, {0.459661, 1.67}, {0.459142, 
  1.68}, {0.456655, 1.69}, {0.452226, 1.7}, {0.44578, 
  1.71}, {0.436996, 1.72}, {0.425101, 1.73}, {0.408591, 
  1.74}, {0.384856, 1.75}, {0.349698, 1.76}};
```

Comment: Fitting a function (a model) to your data is far from trivial task. Firstly, you should probably reverse the $x$ and $y$ (``invData = Reverse[data, 2]``) so that you get a single-valued function. Secondly, you should explain what do you want to achieve by fitting a function. Do you want to _interpolate_ data? Do you want to _extrapolate_ data? Where does this data come from? Do you know of any (physical, economical ...) model that could describe the data?

Comment: Analytical fit-function is needed, not interpolation or extrapolation.

Comment: The main point of fitting data to a model is typically to extract the values of parameters in the model from experimental data. If you don't have a reasonable physical model for your data, and you do not seek to extract further information from it beyond just reproducing the data, then use an interpolation instead.

Comment: @SciJewel Are u asking about what should be a good guess for a closed form function that may fit the data instead of interpolation?

Comment: As others have noted, you probably want to predict `data[[All,1]]` from `data[[All,2]]` as you don't have a function with a single value for every value of `data[[All,1]]`.  *Mathematica*'s regression functions expect the predictor variables (called independent variables in ancient times) to come first and the response variable (called the dependent variable in those ancient times) to be last.  In any event, you should be explicit about which variable is which.

Answer (score 8):

Your data shows a multivalued function. Therefore, you can not simply fit a single valued function. What you can do however, you may interpolate the x and y values separately and define a parametrized function. E.g.:

```
fun[t_] = {Interpolation[data[[All, 1]]][t], 
  Interpolation[data[[All, 2]]][t]}
```

[image]

With this you can do a parametrized plot:

```
ParametricPlot[fun[t], {t, 1, Length[data]}, Epilog -> Point[data]]
```

[image]

Comment: What do mean by multivalued data? This data simply describe a function of one variable. I know the interpolation method. The issue is that I want to know the fit-function and "interpolation" cannot give any information about the fit-function (analytical form)

Comment: But for some x values there are several y values

Comment: Can you point out any such? As I all see all Y-values are unique.

Comment: Look at x~0.35. This could have y around 1.6 or y around 1.7. A function only has one y for each x.

Answer (score 6):

Best, reverse data as @Domen proposes and do simple linear fit. Get good result for order of 11.

```
data = {{0.0270538, 0.92}, {0.0854374, 0.93}, {0.124226, 
    0.94}, {0.14931, 0.95}, {0.16527, 0.96}, {0.175575, 
    0.97}, {0.182765, 0.98}, {0.188613, 0.99}, {0.194274, 
    1.}, {0.200419, 1.01}, {0.207346, 1.02}, {0.215083, 
    1.03}, {0.223469, 1.04}, {0.232232, 1.05}, {0.241039, 
    1.06}, {0.249549, 1.07}, {0.257445, 1.08}, {0.264458, 
    1.09}, {0.270386, 1.1}, {0.275104, 1.11}, {0.278564, 
    1.12}, {0.280794, 1.13}, {0.281891, 1.14}, {0.282012, 
    1.15}, {0.281358, 1.16}, {0.280166, 1.17}, {0.27869, 
    1.18}, {0.27719, 1.19}, {0.275915, 1.2}, {0.275095, 
    1.21}, {0.274926, 1.22}, {0.275567, 1.23}, {0.277128, 
    1.24}, {0.279669, 1.25}, {0.283197, 1.26}, {0.287672, 
    1.27}, {0.293, 1.28}, {0.299049, 1.29}, {0.305648, 1.3}, {0.3126, 
    1.31}, {0.319689, 1.32}, {0.326692, 1.33}, {0.333388, 
    1.34}, {0.339569, 1.35}, {0.345052, 1.36}, {0.349685, 
    1.37}, {0.353355, 1.38}, {0.355998, 1.39}, {0.357599, 
    1.4}, {0.358195, 1.41}, {0.357876, 1.42}, {0.356783, 
    1.43}, {0.3551, 1.44}, {0.353051, 1.45}, {0.350887, 
    1.46}, {0.348878, 1.47}, {0.347298, 1.48}, {0.346412, 
    1.49}, {0.346466, 1.5}, {0.347666, 1.51}, {0.350175, 
    1.52}, {0.35409, 1.53}, {0.359445, 1.54}, {0.366196, 
    1.55}, {0.374222, 1.56}, {0.383326, 1.57}, {0.39324, 
    1.58}, {0.403638, 1.59}, {0.414145, 1.6}, {0.424364, 
    1.61}, {0.43389, 1.62}, {0.442339, 1.63}, {0.449372, 
    1.64}, {0.454715, 1.65}, {0.458178, 1.66}, {0.459661, 
    1.67}, {0.459142, 1.68}, {0.456655, 1.69}, {0.452226, 
    1.7}, {0.44578, 1.71}, {0.436996, 1.72}, {0.425101, 
    1.73}, {0.408591, 1.74}, {0.384856, 1.75}, {0.349698, 1.76}};

ListPlot[data2 = Reverse /@ data, PlotRange -> All]

{min = Min[data2[[All, 1]]], max = Max[data2[[All, 1]]]}

Manipulate[{Plot[
   Evaluate[
    f = LinearModelFit[data2, Table[x^j, {j, 1, jmax}], x] // 
      Normal], {x, min, max}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, Point@data2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, 
   ImageSize -> 400], f}, {{jmax, 11}, 2, 15, 1}]
```

[image]

Get your plot with ParametricPlot or Inversefunction.

Comment: :Do you mean InverseFuction[f] ?

Comment: Why "2, 15, 1"?

Answer (score 6):

Well, it's always possible to fit a polynomial of high degree if you are just looking to fit the data. Extrapolation would probably be out of the question though, but if you are just looking to find area under the curve or something like that, a polynomial would be sufficient.

```
polyMod = LinearModelFit[Reverse[data, 2], Table[x^i, {i, 1, 12}], x]
polyMod["BestFit"]
```

$ 19095.5 - 137063. x + 35576.4 x^2 + 2.26246*10^6 x^3 - 
 9.56685*10^6 x^4 + 2.05022*10^7 x^5 - 2.7615*10^7 x^6 + 
 2.50281*10^7 x^7 - 1.55778*10^7 x^8 + 6.59485*10^6 x^9 - 
 1.81992*10^6 x^{10} + 295831. x^{11} - 21518.7 x^{12} $

```
input=Transpose[data][[2]];
response=Transpose[data][[1]];
Show[ListPlot[Reverse[data, 2]],Plot[polyMod[x], {x, Min@input, Max@input}, PlotStyle -> Green]]
```

[image]

You could then switch the x and y axis data if you want it viewed in the perspective shown in the question.

```
Show[ListPlot[data], ListLinePlot[Transpose[{polyMod[#] & /@ input, input}], PlotStyle -> Green]]
```

[image]

You could always go crazy and fit any sort of strange function to try to get a good fit.

$ -13.8445 + 
 7.70684 ArcTan[
4.27598 + 
 0.173275 Sqrt[
   0.479055 + X1 (2.85861 + X1 Tan[2. X1])]]^2 + (0.00824638 Sin[
 7.38906 (X1)^2])/(2./(X1) - 1. ArcTan[X1]) - 
 0.0287731 Tanh[1. Tanh[1. Sin[58.7434 - 1. Cos[(5.27447 + X1)^2]]]] $

```
Show[Plot[-13.8445+7.70684 ArcTan[4.27598+0.173275 Sqrt[0.479055+X1 (2.85861+X1 Tan[2. X1])]]^2+(0.00824638 Sin[7.38906 (X1)^2])/(2./(X1)-1. ArcTan[X1])-0.0287731 Tanh[1. Tanh[1. Sin[58.7434-1. Cos[(5.27447+X1)^2]]]],{X1,Min@input,Max@input},PlotStyle->Green],ListPlot[Reverse[data,2]]]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListLinePlot[Transpose[{-13.8445+7.70684 ArcTan[4.27598+0.173275 Sqrt[0.479055+X1 (2.85861+X1 Tan[2. X1])]]^2+(0.00824638 Sin[7.38906 (X1)^2])/(2./(X1)-1. ArcTan[X1])-0.0287731 Tanh[1. Tanh[1. Sin[58.7434-1. Cos[(5.27447+X1)^2]]]]/.(X1->input),input}],PlotStyle->Green],ListPlot[data]]
```

[image]

Without context regarding the potential use of the model it is difficult, if not impossible, to know what type of model is desired.

Comment: The trig function is irrelevant. The polynomial is fine, but what are your "inputs"? I mainly need the function in analytical form. How to get it from "Transpose[{polyMod[#] & /@ input, input}]"?

Comment: The definition of input is now added to the post

Comment: If I cannot the fit function in the analytical form at the end, then it's of no use. This method is the same as the "Interpolation" which is rather simple.

Comment: Well if the second value is the independent variable then the analytics form for that polynomial would be the equation shown in the post. For your data is the first value or second value the independent variable? Alternatively, which one would you define as the input to the function you are looking for?

Comment: of course, the first value in the data is independent. In fact the analytical output of Transpose[{polyMod[#] & /@ input, input}] is required.

Comment: @SciJewel Is it possible that there are more than one independent variables driving this system that are not reported in that data? To have values overlapping vertically would seem to imply that there is another variable driving this system other than just the one value shown in the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135422/discussion-between-scijewel-and-nate).

Answer (score 3):

Given that the plot of the data shows values that overlap vertically it would seem that there is likely another driving variable that would allow for this to occur. Without more data this could simply be treated as noise. If we treat those fluctuations as noise we obviously won't have a function that closely fits every point, but it might capture the general trends in the data. An example of this is shown here.

```
Show[ListPlot[data],Plot[0.436094+2.1746 (0.484306+1. Sqrt[2.71828^(1/((x)^2 (-3.14159+13.7321 (x)^3)))])^2,{x,0,0.5},PlotStyle->Green]]
```

[image]

If there is an additional variable that we don't have it could solve all the problems. For example say we create this new data set (the second variable is the new one):

```
altData={{0.0270538,0.135686,0.92},{0.0854374,0.0838094,0.93},{0.124226,0.0504443,0.94},{0.14931,0.0300261,0.95},{0.16527,0.0182274,0.96},{0.175575,0.0117711,0.97},{0.182765,0.00825762,0.98},{0.188613,0.00601191,0.99},{0.194274,0.00394287,1.},{0.200419,0.00141658,1.01},{0.207346,-0.00184847,1.02},{0.215083,-0.00587874,1.03},{0.223469,-0.0105221,1.04},{0.232232,-0.0155217,1.05},{0.241039,-0.0205628,1.06},{0.249549,-0.0253233,1.07},{0.257445,-0.0295038,1.08},{0.264458,-0.0328501,1.09},{0.270386,-0.0351714,1.1},{0.275104,-0.0363495,1.11},{0.278564,-0.0363393,1.12},{0.280794,-0.035167,1.13},{0.281891,-0.0329244,1.14},{0.282012,-0.0297597,1.15},{0.281358,-0.0258629,1.16},{0.280166,-0.0214578,1.17},{0.27869,-0.0167844,1.18},{0.27719,-0.0120884,1.19},{0.275915,-0.0076049,1.2},{0.275095,-0.00355126,1.21},{0.274926,-0.000112627,1.22},{0.275567,0.00256079,1.23},{0.277128,0.00436507,1.24},{0.279669,0.00524353,1.25},{0.283197,0.00518956,1.26},{0.287672,0.00424095,1.27},{0.293,0.00248649,1.28},{0.299049,0.0000509021,1.29},{0.305648,-0.00290428,1.3},{0.3126,-0.00619295,1.31},{0.319689,-0.00961104,1.32},{0.326692,-0.0129479,1.33},{0.333388,-0.0159947,1.34},{0.339569,-0.018555,1.35},{0.345052,-0.0204559,1.36},{0.349685,-0.0215538,1.37},{0.353355,-0.0217419,1.38},{0.355998,-0.0209598,1.39},{0.357599,-0.0191933,1.4},{0.358195,-0.0164774,1.41},{0.357876,-0.012897,1.42},{0.356783,-0.00858548,1.43},{0.3551,-0.00371655,1.44},{0.353051,0.00149815,1.45},{0.350887,0.00682148,1.46},{0.348878,0.0119984,1.47},{0.347298,0.01677,1.48},{0.346412,0.020886,1.49},{0.346466,0.024114,1.5},{0.347666,0.0262593,1.51},{0.350175,0.027168,1.52},{0.35409,0.0267484,1.53},{0.359445,0.0249685,1.54},{0.366196,0.0218697,1.55},{0.374222,0.0175664,1.56},{0.383326,0.0122447,1.57},{0.39324,0.00615778,1.58},{0.403638,-0.000386368,1.59},{0.414145,-0.00703349,1.6},{0.424364,-0.0134085,1.61},{0.43389,-0.0191289,1.62},{0.442339,-0.0238318,1.63},{0.449372,-0.027197,1.64},{0.454715,-0.0289656,1.65},{0.458178,-0.0289582,1.66},{0.459661,-0.0270802,1.67},{0.459142,-0.0233109,1.68},{0.456655,-0.0176824,1.69},{0.452226,-0.0102193,1.7},{0.44578,-0.000850736,1.71},{0.436996,0.0107266,1.72},{0.425101,0.0252429,1.73},{0.408591,0.0441191,1.74},{0.384856,0.0698209,1.75},{0.349698,0.106314,1.76}}
```

This new data is made up so this new model isn't meaningful, but I'll highlight the example here anyway.

```
newFunc[{X1_,X2_}]:=21.0078-0.114172 (X1-1. X2+(-13.4291+X1+X2)^2)

Show[ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Transpose[data][[1]],newFunc[#]&/@Transpose[Transpose[altData][[;;2]]]}],PlotStyle->Green],ListPlot[data]]
```

[image]

Comment: How do you find: 0.436094+2.1746 (0.484306+1. Sqrt[2.71828^(1/((x)^2 (-3.14159+13.7321 (x)^3)))])^2 ?

Comment: I use DataModeler (https://evolved-analytics.com/) when trying to find equations to help explain data when I have no known model form. It’s possible that Mathematica’s FindFormula function could give something similar but I find it to be less useful generally and I believe it can only consider single variable inputs whereas there is no limit when I use DataModeler.

Comment: I see. Can you remove your suggestion "You could always go crazy and fit any sort of strange function to try to get a good fit." and the graph under it. Because it is too much and confusing to others.

Comment: I thought your "You could always go crazy and fit any sort of strange function to try to get a good fit." statement was right on the money.  Sorry to see it removed.

Comment: I added it back into the post. It might not necessarily propose a model that should be used to fit the data but I think its inclusion highlights an important point.

Comment: @Nate: How about if the data is carefully re-digitized scarcely in such a way that the multi-valued function option is avoided. Will "LinearModelFit" work in that case?

Comment: @SciJewel You should be able to use LinearModelFit with the data in its current form. I generally wouldn't advise removing data to make fitting easier.

Comment: @Nate: That's okay, but I am still looking for the right solution. Your solutions are productive and provide additional information, but unfortunately still lack a single variable analytical form. You approximate model [0.436094+2.1746 (0.484306+1. Sqrt[2.71828^(1/((x)^2 (-3.14159+13.7321 (x)^3)))])^2 is closer, but for higher values at X-axis, it does not agree with the data well. Can you tell why the model (Green) goes downward while the data go up and left.

Comment: @SciJewel The model goes to the right since it is not actually possible for the model, using just one variable, to curve back up and to the left. That would lead to a function with to different outputs from the same input, which isn't possible. That is why I wondered if it could be possible that there is another driving variable for your system that was not recorded which allows for that behaviour. Also, it could be useful in your question to clarify what you would consider to be the "right" model.

Comment: @Nate: Unfortunately, the system does not allow a second variable at the moment. It's a strictly one variable system. It will be physically complicated to introduce another variable, though not impossible. Also, it will be time taking to explore it further. Regarding, your question about the "right model", as I have said I need an analytical fit function for this data with one variable and no matter what the number of fit parameters is! Importantly, this function is to be further used as part of another involved calculation.